# Position of class in the style tag varies is effect on the page why?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not that great working with CSS and so posting this here to get some information.

please see the code below where is am displaying a table and whenever mouse moves on a row that row gets highlighted. With the code below I am only getting even rows getting highlighted. But if you move the class "highlight" below the class "stripe2" then every the rows gets highlighted once mouse moves on it. Can someone explain me why the position of class definition effects the display?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Striping/Hover Highlighting a Table</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#theList tr:even").addClass("stripe1");
        $("#theList tr:odd").addClass("stripe2");

        $("#theList tr").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
            }
        );
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
th,td {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
}
tr {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
td {
    width:200px;
    padding:3px;
}
th {
    background-color:#D2E0E8;
    color:#003366
}
table {
    border: 1pt solid gray;
}
.clickable {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.stripe1 {
    background-color:#0f0;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.stripe2 {
    background-color:#afa;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Using jQuery to stripe and hover-highlight a table</h1>
<table id="theList">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>Milk</td>
      <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Eggs</td>
      <td>2.29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Butter</td>
      <td>3.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Bread</td>
      <td>0.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Pasta</td>
      <td>1.19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Honey</td>
      <td>4.39</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Cookies</td>
      <td>2.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>0.59</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>1.78</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Pepper</td>
      <td>1.56</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Style precedence http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Thanks every one! Now I understood the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the classes `.highlight` and `.stripe2` have the same specificity, so which ever comes last in your CSS takes precedence. You can increase the specificity of the highlight to make it independent of the order in your CSS. For example by including the `tr` tag.

`.highlight`, specificity = 10

`tr.highlight`, specificity = 11